# How can I get the crypto currency from the Transaction-ID?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, cryptocurrency

Lets say I have the following Transaction Hash - how do I know what crypto currency was used with this hash?
`e6911d00e77e359a2aa5ee48599636b92a2f738ea9faaee2a03ce1d71be848f6`

https://blockchair.com/search?q=TXID_HERE - Blockchair redirects you to the correct crypto currency page of them once you search for a transaction. How is this possible? What's behind that?

Perhaphs, is there an API for that?

Comment: it's just that the hash are not formatted in the same way between the different blockchains offered by blockchair, so it's easy to recognise them

Comment: Is there an algorithm to recognise it? Can you explain more.

Answer (score 0):

in my project, I tracked the currency by chain id, you can get chain id from the hash also. Then you'll be able to know what chain or currency it is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).